# What is the minimum of this weighted sum, considering all constraints?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, integer-programming

I have started to self-study some non-linear programming courses. In one of the references I have encountered a challenging problem which I was unable to solve it:
Given a number $q, 0 <  < 1$, and a set of positive weights ${_1, _2, … . _}$, the goal is to minimize
the weighted sum $S=\varSigma_{k=0}^n\,\alpha_kq^{x_k}$.The
the sum of all $x_k$ must be less than a total budget T. Moreover, all $x_k$ are non-negative. Also, $x_k$ are non-negative integers that each satisfy some local budget $_ (i.e., 0 ≤ x_k ≤ )$. Find the optimal value for $x_k$.

Comment: The integrality constraint makes it hard. If $T_k$ is reasonably small, you could formulate this as a mixed integer optimization problem.

Comment: On second thought, you can just assign the total budget $T$ in a greedy way: start with $x_k = 0$ for all $k$, find the the largest $\alpha_k q^{x_k}$ for which $x_k < T_k$, increase $x_k$ by $1$, and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to linearize the objective and use an integer linear programming solver.  For $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $i \in \{0,\dots,T_k\}$, introduce binary variable $y_{k,i}$ to indicate whether $x_k = i$.  The problem is to minimize
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k \sum_{i=0}^{T_k} q^i y_{k,i}$$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{T_k} y_{k,i} &= 1 &&\text{for all $k$}\\ 
\sum_{i=0}^{T_k} i y_{k,i} &= x_k &&\text{for all $k$}\\ 
\sum_{k=0}^n x_k &\le T
\end{align}